# Why does power driven to the load has this expression?

Tags: power, amplifier, bjt, oscillator, load

I'm designing an oscillator, I'm using as textbook Krauss one.

I would like to design the oscillator In function of the power it must give to the load and the fundamental frequency.

I have seen this expression in bjt amplifier design too.

According to this books, the power driven to the load (RL) is:

P = Icq<sup>2</sup> × R<sub>L</sub>/8

So Krauss find the transistor's Q-point with this expression knowing the load and the power he wants.

I have try to deduce this equation and I have got this expression.

Let's assume the current (I) is the current across the load resistor (for example, using a simulator and measuring this signal).

P(rms) = I<sub>RMS</sub><sup>2</sup> × R<sub>L</sub>.

P(rms) = I<sub>peak</sub><sup>2</sup> × R<sub>L</sub> / 2.

P(rms) = I<sub>p-p</sub><sup>2</sup> × R<sub>L</sub> / 8.

It's a similar expression, however it depends on the alternal current across the indictor, not Q-point.

**How can I relation this expression with Q-point?**

---

Also I have another question, let's say I have a voltage amplifier (CE). It has a gain of 2.

If the input signal is 1, I would have 2 volts in the output. So my RL with have this 2 volts signal across it, and this would generate a power.

Now I have 2 volts in the input, this will generate 4 volts in RL. So the power will increase.

According to this, the power depends on the input, the amplifier gain and the RL, not Q-point, **so how does this expression makes valid ?**

P(rms) = Icq<sup>2</sup> × R<sub>L</sub>/8

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRV0bT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thank you.

Comment: What does 'ICQ' mean? (Explain it in your question, not in the comments.)

Comment: Q=Xc/R for series and R/Xc for parallel and Xc(fo)=XL(fo) at fo resonance. There must be some assumption for max power at some Q for stability or signal BW with feedback gain overall >1.

Comment: Doesn't make all that much sense without a schematic.

Comment: Sorry for the semantic, I'm Spanish, we call ICQ to the Q-point of the transistor's (it's the same for DC and AC)

Comment: then use Icq instead

Comment: Consider Icq as the average current and Ic-pp as the AC output current swing into R ? You didn’t specify if you were dealing with peak, average or RMS power, so your uncertainty is due to this

Comment: I’m sure you can figure it out.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The power is RMS.

I deduce by myself the equation of RMS Power in function of Ic-pp. The problem is that I can't understand how does the other equation P(rms) = Icq^2 × RL/8 was deduced, because that Icq is the same as the average current (that does not makes sense to me)

Comment: It's kind of a useless formula due to other issues like THD and  bias clipping, Try this one for linearity https://tinyurl.com/yffhu8xv